# optimize the array with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I agree to build a function that will calculate "priceinterval". This means that you build an array that you want to assign values for exampel number between 1-3 to assign "1-3" example $array [2] => "1-3" and 4-10 $array[5] => "4-10"
I've built a function that works but want optimize function, someone who is good at for-loops;)

```
public function CalcPris() {

    $Prisinterval = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        array_push($Prisintervall, "1-3");
    }
    if ($i = 4) {
        for ($i = 4; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            array_push($Prisintervall, "4-10");
        }
    }
    if ($i = 11) {
        for ($i = 11; $i <= 50; $i++) {
            array_push($Prisintervall, "11-50");
        }
    }
    if ($i = 51) {
        for ($i = 51; $i <= 100; $i++) {
            array_push($Prisintervall, "51-100");
        }
    }
    var_dump($Prisinterval);
}
```

the reason for this feature is that you should get a price floor.

in my next step is to check what the number "2" is worth, therefore, Please I build an array that has already been completed as has the value 1-100

Comment: What is the purpose of the if tests to start with? and where are you sending in a value?

Comment: Your function doesn't even accept an input value, I have no clue what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: All the `if ($i = X)` should be `if ($i == X)`, at the very least. And, as others said, your function does not take in a value. It only sets up a price interval array.

Comment: Andriaon, concept of function is that it will fill an array with the different host groups.

Comment: "Andriaon" is a new form of writing my name. You should actually read my comment.

Comment: -1, think about what you want _before_ asking people to devote their time.

Comment: Adriano - The problem is that I need to build an array of value from the array number 1 to 3 where the value should be "1-3" and then from the array numbers 4-10 will be worth "4-10"

Comment: That's not what you're telling @Itroubs. You want to build the array first for some reason, which you didn't specify. And please, stop saying "the code works". Your code does not work. It contains logic errors, and doesn't even fulfill your requirements.

Comment: i now got it too... but his aproach is actually not that intelligent... making a function like i proposed is memory efficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach is totally off...
you want something like this:

```
function printerval($int){
    if($int >= 1 && $int <= 3){
        return "1-3"; 
    }elseif($int >= 4 && $int <= 10){
        return "4-10";
    }elseif($int >= 11 && $int <= 50){
        return "11-50";
    }elseif($int >= 51 && $int <= 100){
        return "51-100";
    }   
    return "error";
}
```

calling `printerval(2);` will return the string "1-3"

well here is the stupid thing that seems to be requested:

```
function printerval(){
    $arr= array();
    for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
        if($i >= 1 && $i <= 3){
            $arr[$i]= "1-3"; 
        }elseif($i >= 4 && $i <= 10){
            $arr[$i]=  "4-10";
        }elseif($i >= 11 && $i <= 50){
            $arr[$i]=  "11-50";
        }elseif($i >= 51 && $i <= 100){
            $arr[$i]=  "51-100";
        }   
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

although that is the wrong approach it should now answer the question..

Comment: All I want is if a user sends in numbers "2" and I'll retunera out "1-3"

Comment: All I want is if a user sends in numbers "2" and I'll retunera out "1-3"

Comment: I think he wants to return a price interval that covers the input value. E.g., the interval that covers input "2" is "1-3".

Comment: and if user send again "3" i will return "1-3".

Comment: if i got it right you want to return 1-3 if the user sends 2 and 11-50 if the user sends 20?

Comment: just now, will i only put up an array so that I can check which one right after

Comment: but this should be run before the user enters their value so $ int can not. When users launch the application to build an array of the different host groups. That's where I am right now. then will I make an if statement that checks which one is right.

Comment: what the hell? ever thought about making a propper description of your problem? my solution is the answer to your question. the fact that it is not at the right palce is not of concern for the question you posted!

Comment: ledsen om frågan är dåligt formulerad. men mitt mål är att skapa en array av värde där antalet 1 till 3 tilldelas => "1-3" och 4-10 => "4-10". Jag måste vara ett pristrip som det kallas för att kontrollera användaren senare då vad hans siffror är värda.

Comment: creating some kind of array that looks like this: `array(1-4 => "1-4", ....)` is impossible!

Comment: Is not impossible? The code up there doing the exact. What I want is for it to optimize with less for-loops.

Comment: your code is absolutely inefficient because the way i did it would be more memory efficient to work with.

Comment: But you do not have $int value to work with. This code is generated when starting the application :)

Comment: @Mrmaxen $int was introduced to fulfill _your_ requirement of "you send in a value example". $int _is_ the value you send in. If you didn't want that, you should edit your question and tell us what you really want.

Comment: i think he doesn't know what he wants or he want's us to do the conceptual and the actual programming work...

Comment: So Adriano. (edited now) would not make a fuss, I need help with is to omptimze my for loop statement

Comment: @ITroubs please read http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx

Comment: haha nice post XD but since he is kind of stubborn I had no "choice"... @AdrianoVaroliPiazza

Comment: " Undefined variable: int"

Comment: if you can't solf that problem you should really stop asking for money if you do some kind of commercial work! nevertheless i will correct my answer so that error doesn't appear anymore!

Comment: Will truly apologize. There was a little error in the description. I take in with me of your criticism! thx!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to optimize this function, you should do the following:

1. Go to the nearest technical bookstore, or register at oreilly.com.
2. Buy a copy of [Learning PHP5](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005603.do).
3. Read the book and understand the difference between `if ($x = 4)` and `if ($x == 4)`.
4. Read the book and learn about for-loops and arrays.